# SVN checksum mismatch on checkout, but only on one specific computer

Tags: svn, checksum, mismatch, svn-checkout

A remote contractor I'm working with is getting checksum mismatch errors when they try to checkout a project. This error only happens on their desktop machine. I don't have an issue with the repository on my machine and they were able to checkout the project without issue on another computer. Any ideas as to what could be going on and how to fix it?

Disabling all firewall/antivirus didn't work. It's a win10 machine and we're using TortiseSVN 1.9.7. I've also tried running from the command line

```
svn update --set-depth empty
svn update --set-depth infinity
```

Any ideas? Thanks